# Adding a new item to a windows form application combo box without touching the datasource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to add a new item to a windows form application combo box without touching the datasource, like we add it in a web application, using Items.Insert(index, newItem).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think this would do the trick - after you bind the data source to the ComboBox, add the additional items:

```
CombBox1.Items.Insert(0, "New Item");
```

Are you having problems getting that to work?

**EDIT**
Did some research via google - turns out you can't add items after the ComboBox is databound.  You have to add the items to the datasource itself.  For example, say you're binding a DataTable to the ComboBox, with the DisplayMember set to column 1 and the ValueMember set to column 0:

```
DataRow newRow = myDataTable.NewRow();

newRow[0] = "0";
newRow[1] = "aa";

myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

cb1.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

Comment: yes I tried it like this before but couldn;t get it to work, maybe because the combo box has it's datasource already set

Comment: ddl.DisplayMember = displayMember; ddl.ValueMember = valueMember; ddl.DataSource = myDataSource; ddl.Items.Insert(0, "aa");

Comment: Yes I agree with you that you cant add items after the combo box is databound, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no `drop down list` in windows forms however you maybe referring to `ComboBox`, so use `myComboBox.Items.Add` or `myComboBox.Items.AddRange` or `myComboBox.Items.Insert`

Comment: Cant add items after databinding

Comment: He should then `unbind` the data first.

Comment: Or just add the items to the source before binding would make more sense.